# Why are the DXF files not to scale when i import them into blender?

Tags: import

All of my measurements seem to be their actual values when I view them with Autocad but the measurements are way too large when I import the DXF file into blender. For example, a three feet door drawing in Autocad is about more than 10 feet when I import it to blender. As a complete beginner this problem has got me scratching my head for a few hours now. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Did you change blender's unit system to imperial before importing?

Comment: You may need to change the unit scale in the importer

Comment: Changing the unit scale in the importer fixed the issue :) Thank you all for such prompt response.

Comment: Pls refer this video for imperial import https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bje4tCOLHCM